# How do I insert an empty row, but have the autonumber update correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was hoping to be able to do something like

```
INSERT INTO `table`;
```

or maybe even a SET clause like

```
SET `primary_key` = null
```

where all the columns of the table aren't set (and are left to their default), with the exception of the autonumbered primary key which should be set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (non, primary, key, columns) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);` (assuming the columns are nullable).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`primary_key`) VALUES (NULL);
```

Comment: Ah. That's what I was doing before, but getting an error. Turns out I had the primary key set wrong. Sigh. Thanks!

Comment: See Linus Unnebäck's answer below for postgres 12, this no longer seems to work

Answer (score 46):

```
INSERT INTO `table` () VALUES();
```

Comment: It is nicely simple.

Comment: See Linus Unnebäck's answer below for postgres 12, this no longer seems to work

Comment: @JustinFuruness Just tried with MySQL Version 10.3.32-MariaDB-cll-lve and all works.

Comment: @Andris I was more so referring to Postgres12 specifically. Great that it works with MySQL still!

Answer (score 40):

I believe that the more correct answer would be this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table DEFAULT VALUES
```

As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13605273/148072

Comment: Only answer here that worked for me  (Postgres 12).

Comment: Tried `INSERT INTO table_name DEFAULT VALUES;` with MySQL Version 10.3.32-MariaDB-cll-lve and got `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT VALUES' at line 1`

Answer (score 7):

A little late.. But maybe handy for anyone looking for this answer.

```
INSERT INTO `table` () VALUES ()
```

You do not need any specification of the primary key.

Comment: Duplicate added 4 years later.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your table. If it allows null values on every field, just do an insert with all values as null. If it does not allow null values for every field, you will need to insert a row with those fields having some value.