# How to insert an empty line to SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting rows into a table with one IDENTITY column only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117676/inserting-rows-into-a-table-with-one-identity-column-only)

I have a SQL table with just one column. Column is an autoincrement field like:

```
Id INT IDENTITY
```

I need to insert a rows to this table (this is a bulk/dummy table temporarily):

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ()
```

But I'm got a syntax error.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO my_table DEFAULT VALUES
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75183/3/1

Comment: What if I want to do it for thousands of rows? Is there any smarter way than just doing this thousands of times?

Comment: You can add multiple rows like this: 
`INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (DEFAULT), (DEFAULT)`

Comment: I tried this and it gives me an error saying: "DEFAULT is not valid at this postion expecting PARTITION, SELECT, SET, TABLE, VALUE,..."

Answer (score 3):

Try to insert explicit null values:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (NULL, NULL);
```